# ValueError: Unconverted data remains .000

Tags: python, csv, datetime, strptime

I'm super new to Python and just got thrown for a loop when my source csv file changed its format. The date field now has this: `2020-07-22T00:00:00.000` when what I want is this: `2020-07-22`.

I need to read the source csv and append it to a database table. I looked at some other questions and found this sample code which I think will do what I want (create a copy of the csv with the newly formatted date which I can use with the rest of my code).

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

with open(csvCasesVH, 'r') as source:
    with open(csvCasesVH2, 'w') as result:
        writer = csv.writer(result, lineterminator='\n')
        reader = csv.reader(source)
        source.readline()
        for row in reader:
            ts = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            print(ts)
            row[0]=ts
            if ts != "":
                writer.writerow(row)
source.close()
result.close()
```

I'm trying to figure out the datetime format - almost got there but now that this .000 hanging out there I don't know what to do with:

ValueError: unconverted data remains: .000

I would appreciate any advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try updating the line:

`ts = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`

To:

`ts = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`

Note the `.%f` which is for microseconds

Answer (score 1):

The strptime function tries to get a datetime object out of a string, to do that it needs a datetime string and it needs a format matching the string. For example lets say I have the string '25/07/2020 21:13', to extract a date I need to give it the format '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', if I gave it the format '%d/%m/%Y %H:' it would give the error `ValueError: unconverted data remains: 13` because it doesn't know what the 13 stands for (minutes?, seconds?, am/pm?). To solve this problem you can look at how the string looks like by printing it and modifying the format.

A useful site to use when working with datetime formats is https://strftime.org/.

In your case the remaining .000 probably means microseconds so you need to add it to the format: `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'` (%f stands for microsecconds)

Answer (score 1):

Try use `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f000'` as the formatting string:

applying to your code:

```
ts = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f000').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```